# How to Build RPM of a maven project to be installed on remote systems

Tags: maven, rpm, rpmbuild

I have build a maven project of inventory management on restlet framework and i use MYSQL.
Now I need to build a RPM of it so that it works on even remote systems by just installing the RPM

Comment: Have you tried the [Maven RPM Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/)?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know anything about building RPMs or you want an all-Maven method, you should try the [RPM plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/).

If you want to construct the RPM yourself, you can use the [Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) which will let you mush all your code and dependencies into a single JAR, making it trivial to package. (But you may not be able to distribute this outside your organization, depending on copyrights.)

Finally, if you want to keep your jars separate, you can use the [Dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to list all dependencies and do all the packaging yourself from scratch.

None of these suggestions includes RPM dependencies, because there generally aren't RPMs of Java libraries. You'll depend on some version of Java, of course, but otherwise your RPM will probably have to hold all your dependencies.